# reversing Refactored Storyboards

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

Once I have refactored my 'Main' storyboard to 'Main' and 'Second' storyboard, is there a way to reverse the refactoring back to all the view controllers in 'Main' storyboard

Comment: Do you use any distributed version control system like Git? If yes, revert to the previous commit.

Comment: I know it can be manually be done by deleting storyboard references in 'Main' and moving the ViewController Interface from  'Second' storyboard to 'Main' but is there a better way

Comment: @Sachin Vas, yes I do use, and your solution will work but my question is through Xcode IB itself is there some way to get the refactoring reverted.

Comment: You can get the storyboard changes by viewing it as source code. However, you might be editing some unwanted changes. I wouldn't prefer doing it.